# Chef cookbook not seeing overridden attributes in another cookbook

Tags: attributes, vagrant, chef-infra, chef-solo

I have a run_list like this `[ recipe["git_deploy"], recipe["my_role_cookbook"] ]`
I set attributes that git_deploy needs in the default.rb recipe of my_role_cookbook. However, the git_deploy doesn't get these attributes. 
If I put the attribute needed by git_deploy in my_role_cookbook/attributes/default.rb, then it works. If I put lazy evaluation in git_deploy - it works as well.
I don't get why it doesn't work if I use node.override in the `my_rolecook_book/recipes/default.rb`

The bigger picture: I have three environments, and in the role file of my_role, I have env_run_lists like this:

```
"production" => ["recipe[git_deploy]","recipe[my_role]"],
"staging" =>["recipe[git_deploy]","recipe[my_role]"],
"develop" => ["recipe[my_role]"]
```

**EDIT**
After using `debug_value` in both cookbooks:

- When using lazy evaluation in git_deploy(node.override used in my_role_cookbook/recipe/default.rb):

  - Chef::Log output from git_deploy
    `[2015-07-31T11:44:12+00:00] FATAL: [["set_unless_enabled?", false], ["default", :not_present], ["env_default", :not_present], ["role_default", :not_present], ["force_default", :not_present], ["normal", :not_present], ["override", :not_present], ["role_override", :not_present], ["env_override", :not_present], ["force_override", :not_present], ["automatic", :not_present]]`
  - LOG output from my_role_cookbook
    `[2015-07-31T11:44:12+00:00] FATAL: [["set_unless_enabled?", false], ["default", :not_present], ["env_default", :not_present], ["role_default", :not_present], ["force_default", :not_present], ["normal", :not_present], ["override", "youtube-minion"], ["role_override", :not_present], ["env_override", :not_present], ["force_override", :not_present], ["automatic", :not_present]]`
- When not using lazy evaluation(only node.override in my_role_cookbook)

  - LOG from git_deploy. Right after the log with debug_value, the git_deploy fails with `` undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass ``

  `[2015-07-31T11:45:53+00:00] FATAL: [["set_unless_enabled?", false], ["default", :not_present], ["env_default", :not_present], ["role_default", :not_present], ["force_default", :not_present], ["normal", :not_present], ["override", :not_present], ["role_override", :not_present], ["env_override", :not_present], ["force_override", :not_present], ["automatic", :not_present]]`

  - LOG from my_role_cookbook - this LOG is not shown, because the previous recipe fails.

Comment: Give [debug_value](https://docs.chef.io/debug.html#debug-value) a try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added the output from the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All files inside `attributes/*` are merged and evaluated before any recipes run. Since you've put `git_deploy` first on your runlist, it's recipes run before yours. You must use attribute files in order to get your attributes injected before git deploy's recipes, and then your recipe, runs. Or put git_deploy as an include from your recipe.

Here's a link with more on [how attribute files work](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_attribute_files.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response, Martin :) I am bit confused though, I thought that during compile stage,  the node.override statements will be evaluated and at the end of the compile stage, all attributes will be set according to the precedence. And after that, during the converge stage, the attributes will be applied. Thanks

Comment: @JoroTenev: You're correct that `node.override` would be evaluated at the compile stage. But since the git deploy recipes were evaluated first, and resources within them were built, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks Martin - much appreciated. However, I was reading the chef docs and I keep seeing stuff that confuses me. [This link](https://docs.chef.io/run_lists.html#attribute-evaluation-order), in the Reset node attributes  section, and also this [link](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html) in the Deep merge section. I really want to understand how things work and I have a feeling that what the docs say and what I see from experiments differ which bothers me. Cheers

Comment: I think what you're missing is that all attributes are evaluated in cookbook order, and then all recipes are evaluated in cookbook order. Since the git deploy cookbook's recipes are both compiled and converged before yours, you cannot affect them unless you re-order the recipe or insert attributes with a higher precedence using an attribute file, so that it overrides the precedence of attribute files in git deploy. 

Your link specifically talks about attributes defined in attribute files. But you're setting them in a recipe (which is less common).

Comment: `I think what you're missing is that all attributes are evaluated in cookbook order, and then all recipes are evaluated in cookbook order.` This what I was missing - thanks a lot. I am currently setting all my attributes either in environment files or in the attribute folder of a cookbook. Thanks again :)